# Android chart4j label color

Tags: android, bar-chart, charts4j

I am working on an graph based android application. So I used chart4j library.
I have created the bar chart using the following code.

```
   BarChart chart = GCharts.newBarChart( team1, team2, team3,team4,team5,team6,team7 );

    // Defining axis info and styles


    // Adding axis info to chart.
    ArrayList<String> weeksry=new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < suns.size(); i++) {

        weeksry.add("week"+(i+1));
    }

    chart.addXAxisLabels( AxisLabelsFactory.newAxisLabels( weeksry ) );
    chart.addYAxisLabels( AxisLabelsFactory.newNumericRangeAxisLabels( 0, 100 ) );


    chart.setSize(  300, 153 );
    chart.setBarWidth( 30 );
    chart.setSpaceWithinGroupsOfBars( 25 );
    chart.setDataStacked( true );
    chart.setTitle( " My Complaince Chart", BLACK, 12 );
    chart.setGrid( 100, 10, 3, 2 );
    chart.setBackgroundFill( Fills.newSolidFill(  com.googlecode.charts4j.Color.ROYALBLUE) );

    LinearGradientFill fill = Fills.newLinearGradientFill( 0, com.googlecode.charts4j.Color.ROYALBLUE, 100 );
    fill.addColorAndOffset( com.googlecode.charts4j.Color.ROYALBLUE, 0 );
    chart.setAreaFill( fill );
```

Now I want to change the xaxix and yaxix label colors. I searched for availbale methods But I couldn't. Please help me to solve my problem